# Unexpected token 'workspace' in expression or statment in powershell script calling TF.exe

Tags: powershell, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am writing a PowerShell (version 5.1) script to get the latest source code from TFS for a particular project and I'm getting the error:

```
"Unexpected token 'workspace' in expression or statement."
```

I've searched here and googled the error but cannot find a specific reference to this error. I've tried a multitude of combinations with the syntax and using single-quotes vs double-quotes etc. and have not had any success.  I don't understand what the issue is...

This is the code:

```
$TFdir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer"
$TF="'$TFdir\tf.exe'"
$WorkSpaceName="C:\temp\NewTestBuildProject"
$expr="$TF workspace /new $WorkSpaceName /noprompt /collection:http://(servername):8080/tfs/defaultcollection"

$expr
```

This is what the line above evaluates to:

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe' workspace /new C:\temp\NewTestBuildProject /noprompt /collection:http://(servername):8080/tfs/defaultcollection
```

This is line that executes the above expression and is where the error is generated:

```
Invoke-Expression $expr
```

This is the error it generates:

```
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:143
+ ... ions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe' workspace /new 
C: ...
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'workspace' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\PF12764\Desktop\PS\PublishWithPowerShell.ps1:42 char:1
+ Invoke-Expression $expr
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], 
ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
UnexpectedToken,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Comment: i think you will need to look into the `&` call operator OR use the `Start-Process` cmdlet so that you can gracefully pass in arguments to the exe.

Comment: Lee_Dailey, you are correct!

This command works:

    & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe" workspace /new mytemp /noprompt /collection:http://(server):8080/tfs/defaultcollection

Comment: kool! glad to know you got it working ... [*grin*]

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT, is there some way to mark Lee_Dailey's comment as a reply and give him the credit since it was really his answer that was correct?

Comment: @DevilDog - no credit is needed since the answer was pretty clear once you had time to think about it. thank you, tho! [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lee_Dailey, you are correct! This command works:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe" workspace /new mytemp /noprompt /collection:http://(server):8080/tfs/defaultcollection
```